# How to filter data from an object with multi select options in TypeScript

Tags: angular, typescript

```
const myArray = [
  { name: "Alice", age: 35, state: "MI", salary:"60000" },
  { name: "Bob", age: 40, state: "MI", salary:"60000"},
  { name: "Carmen", age: 50, state: "MA", salary:"60000"},
  { name: "Danilo", age: 35, state: "MI", salary:"60000"}
  { name: "Carmen", age: 50, state: "MA", salary:"70000"},
  { name: "Carmen", age: 50, state: "FL", salary:"70000"},
]
```

I have multi select options for age, state and salary.

If I select multiple ages = 35, 40, state= MI and salary = 60000 then it should return the following:

```
[
  { name: "Alice", age: 35, state: "MI", salary:"60000" },
  { name: "Bob", age: 40, state: "MI", salary:"60000"},
  { name: "Danilo", age: 35, state: "MI", salary:"60000"}
]
```

So, it should show records that have ages= (35 or 40) and state = MI and salary = 60000

If I select multiple states= MI, MA and multiple salaries = 60000, 70000 then it should return the following:

```
 [
  { name: "Alice", age: 35, state: "MI", salary:"60000" },
  { name: "Bob", age: 40, state: "MI", salary:"60000"},
  { name: "Carmen", age: 50, state: "MA", salary:"60000"},
  { name: "Danilo", age: 35, state: "MI", salary:"60000"}
  { name: "Carmen", age: 50, state: "MA", salary:"70000"},
]
```

So, it should show records that have states = (MI or MA) and salaries = (60000 or 70000)

How do I write a method in TypeScript that returns the above results. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

As you mentioned, the filter conditions are dynamic. You have to filter the data more than one time. Luckily, the filter function of array is chained. Example：

```
x = [1,2,3,4]
x.filter(i => i > 1).filter(i => i > 2).filter(i => i > 3) // 4
```

now we have the function:

```js
const filterEmployee = (employees: Employee[], ages: number[], states: string[], salaries: string[]) => 
  employees.filter(({age}) => ages&&ages.length ? ages.indexOf(age) > -1 : true)
    .filter(({state}) => states&&states.length ? states.indexOf(state) > -1 : true)
    .filter(({salary}) => salaries&&salaries.length ? salaries.indexOf(salary) > -1 : true)
```

You can call the function with dynamic parameters, like:

```
filterEmployee(myArray, [35, 40])
filterEmployee(myArray, [35, 40], ['MA'])
filterEmployee(myArray, [35, 40], ['MA', 'MI'])
filterEmployee(myArray, [35, 40], ['MA'], ['60000'])
```

You will get the result.

Answer (score 0):

If all attributes are mandatory in object you could solve in this way

```js
applyFilter(data, age, state, salary) {
  return data.filter(
    item => age === item.age && state === item.state && salary === item.salary
  );
}
```

Where data is array of options.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `filter` option to filter you array based on your condition.

**Case 1:**
multiple ages = 35, 40, state= MI and salary = 60000

```
myArrary.filter((item) => (item.age === 35 || item.age === 40) && item.state === 'MI' && item.salary === '60000');
```

**Case 2:** multiple states= MI, MA and multiple salaries = 60000, 70000

```
myArray.filter((item) => (item.state === 'MI' || item.state === 'MA') && (item.salary === '60000' || item.salary === '70000'))
```

Comment: How do I make it dynamic as I should be able to select any number of states/ages/salaries.. Also, selecting all 3 is not mandatory. I mean to say I can just select 2 states, 1 state 2 salaries, 4 states 1 salary 3 ages..

Comment: can you create a sample project in stackblitz.com regarding this?

Comment: I saw @Aison's response while I was creating the project and that worked. Thanks for your time...